# UNION ALL not working with different columns

Tags: mysql, union

Left join rows and right table rows in same column

I have two tables (Manager and Worker). The name of  workers under a manager should come below manager name. The expected output is presented below:-

```
Manager Table:

ManagerCode   Name  Age Location
1             Chris  52  A
2             Rick   55  B
3             David  50  C


Worker Table

ManagerCode   WName Age
1             Harry  33
1             Phil   40
2             Johnny 28
2             Jeff   47

Expected table:

ManagerCode   Name    Location
1            Chris      A
1            Harry      A
1            Phil       A
2            Rick       B
2            Johnny     B
2            Jeff       B
3            David      C
```

Union All is creating problem for Location column as number of columns become different. I could use null as Location for worker table. But there are several columns like location in Manager. Is union correct option ?

Comment: You should use `JOIN` to get the location code for the workers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the Worker and Manager tables to get the location codes for the workers from their corresponding managers. Then you can union that with the manager table.

```
SELECT ManagerCode, Name, Location
FROM (
    SELECT ManagerCode, Name, Location, 1 AS isManager
    FROM Manager

    UNION ALL

    SELECT w.ManagerCode, w.Name, m.Locationm, 0 AS isManager
    FROM Worker AS w
    JOIN Manager AS m ON w.ManagerCode = m.ManagerCode
) AS x
ORDER BY ManagerCode, isManager DESC
```

The `isManager` column is used to order the workers after their managers.